# New location path for converted file type in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to convert .TIF files to .PNG using PowerShell. The script successfully converted the file and saved the file in the same folder/path. I would like for the script to save the newly created file to a new location. I have defined the destination path but i not sure where i can add the expression to save it in that destination path.

This is my first time coding, apologies if the solution is simple.

```
function ConvertImage{
param ([string]$path)
$_sourcepath="C:\Users\Name\Documents\File_TIFF" #path to source files
$_destinationpath="C:\Users\Name\Documents\File_PNG" #path to destination files
if (Test-Path $_sourcepath)

#Load required assemblies and get object reference
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
foreach($file in (ls "$_sourcepath\*.TIF")){
    $convertfile = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap($file.Fullname)
    $newfilname = ($file.Fullname -replace '([^.]).TIF','$1') + ".PNG"
    $convertfile.Save($newfilname, "PNG") 
    $file.Fullname
    }  
 }
else
 {
Write-Host "Path not found."
 }
};ConvertImage -path $args[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$newfilname = ($file.Fullname -replace '([^.]).TIF','$1') + ".PNG"`

should be:

```
$newfilname = $_destinationpath + '\' + $file.BaseName + '.PNG'
```

A few asides:

- You're passing a path to your function's `-path` parameter (`$path`), but you're not using it.
- Re `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null`:

  - It is simpler and more PowerShell-idiomatic to use
    `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms`
- Re `new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap($file.Fullname)`:

  - It best to avoid such pseudo method syntax: instead of `New-Object SomeType(arg1, ...)`, use `New-Object SomeType [-ArgumentList] arg1, ...` - PowerShell cmdlets and functions are invoked like *shell commands* , not like *methods*. That is, no parentheses around the argument list, and *whitespace*-separated arguments.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @EVCode. See  [`about_Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions) for how to declare parameters; if you have specific questions about that, I suggest you ask a new question.